# Problems with zooming

Tags: php, html, css, zooming

I've recently started learning HTML, CSS and PHP.
I'm creating a site for school but there are some problems when I zoom in google chrome and internet explorer, I haven't tested other browsers yet. My contact form is going to fly when I zoom in.

This is my header:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mijn website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="opmaak.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/header.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; margin: 0px;                     
 padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-size: 0px;" />
<!-- Comment !-->
<header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo "<form action='includes/logout.inc.php'>
        <button> Log out </button>
        </form>";
        } else {
        echo "<form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'> 
        <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'> 
        <button type='submit'>Login</button>
        </form>";
        }

        ?>
        <li><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

This is the contact page:

```
    <?php
include 'header.php';
?>

<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$errors = array();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) ===             
 true) {
    $errors[] = 'Name, email and message are required!';
}
else {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That\'s not a valid email address';
    }
}

if (empty($errors) === true) {
    echo "<h1>Thanks for contacting us $name</h1>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "We will send a reply to $email soon!";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Your message: $message";
};

}
?>

<?php
if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<br />';

}
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo    "<form action='' method='POST' style='height: 200px; width:     
 400px; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -5%; margin-left:     
 -15% ;'>
            <p>
                <label for='name'> Name: </label><br />
                <input type='text' name='name' id='name' style='width: 100%;     
 padding: 15px; background:#f8f8f8; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); 
 margin-bottom:25px; color:#727272 !important; font-size:13px; -webkit-
 transition: all 0.4s; -moz-transition: all 0.4s; transition: all 0.4s;'>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='email'>Email:</label><br />
                <input type='text' name='email' id='email' style='width: 
 100%; padding: 15px; background:#f8f8f8; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 
 0.075); margin-bottom:25px; color:#727272 !important; font-size:13px; -
 webkit-transition: all 0.4s; -moz-transition: all 0.4s; transition: all 
 0.4s;'>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='message'>Message:</label><br />
                <textarea name='message' id='message' style='width: 100%; 
 padding: 15px; background:#f8f8f8; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); 
 margin-bottom:25px; color:#727272 !important; font-size:13px; -webkit-
 transition: all 0.4s; -moz-transition: all 0.4s; transition: all 0.4s;'>
 </textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' style='padding:8px 12px; 
 color: #fff; background:#000; display: block; width:120px; margin:10px 0 
 0px 0; border-radius:3px; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; -moz-transition: 
 all 0.3s; transition: all 0.3s; text-align:center; font-size:0.8em; box-
 shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 
 rgba(0,0,0, 0.10); -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);'>
            </p>
            </form>  ";
} else {
    echo "You do not have permission to view this page, please log in.";
}

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
    * {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #222;
}

nav ul {
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 60px;
}

nav ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
color: #fff;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul form {
float: left;
}

nav ul form input {
float: left;
border: none;
margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul form button {
float: left;
border: none;
margin-right: 6px;
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#registreren {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Normal view: [image]

Problem: [image]

Comment: you are not really meant to view websites zoomed in. If you still want to do it, then I would recommend creating a responsive css for required effect. Read more about it on w3schools.

Comment: yeah, as long as it adapts to the desired screen sizes you're good to go

Comment: @tei, could you embed your images rather than using an external link?

Comment: @Chic Not with 1 reputation, they can't. I just did it for them.

Comment: Consider linking a normalize.css/reset.css file instead of using * { } to "reset" element styling across browsers. Normalize will make element styling more consistent across browsers, and reset will set every element to have minimal styling. You can also edit both files to meet your needs.

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Include your HTML.